# Maximum number of cookies per browser (not per hostname)

Tags: browser, cookies

Does anyone know if there is a maximum number of cookies that a browser can hold, across all domains?  Does anyone know what these maximums are for modern broswers and the default settings?

For example, this artcle states that FireFox 3 had a default of 1000 and that this was in the network.cookie.maxNumber setting:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Cookies_Preferences_in_Mozilla

When I go to about:config in my FF7, i don't see a setting for network.cookie.maxNumber.  Was this removed?  Is there no maximum anymore in Firefox?  Did the setting change names?

What about Chrome, Safari, and IE?

To be clear I am not interested in maximum per host, but for all hosts.

Answer (score 1):

The maximum allowed cookies per browser varies heavily per browser, and the only way to know for sure would be to perform some tests (which would be hard if you don't own multiple domains).  [RFC 2109](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2109.txt) sets some minimums for cookies (at least 300 per user agent at 4096 bytes each), but no maximums. IE6 does not honor this.

Here is a (probably outdated) list for Firefox: http://www.ghacks.net/2008/08/16/browser-cookie-limits/

Answer (score 0):

None of this is really officially documented as far as I can tell. Here is what I do know:

1. Internet Explorer 6 is limited to 300. [Reference](http://www.thismuchiknow.co.uk/?p=13)
2. Chrome seems to limit it to 3,300. This can be seen in [Chrome's Source](http://src.chromium.org/svn/trunk/src/net/base/cookie_monster.cc). (`CookieMonster::kMaxCookies`) This *appears* to be shared code from Firefox as well.
3. Couldn't find anything regarding Safari.

Answer (score 0):

For Firefox, the config entry for network.cookie.maxNumber does not appear by default, but if you declare it yourself (about:config -> right-click -> New -> Integer), you can override it. According to the [mozillaZine wiki](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Network.cookie.maxNumber), the default value for network.cookie.maxNumber is 1000.

P.S. in case anyone wants to know, the comparable config value for per-host is network.cookie.maxPerHost